# (laravel8) ErrorException Undefined variable $eshop (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/alleshops/resources/views/edit_eshop.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->any('/edit_eshop/{eshop}', function () {
    return view('edit_eshop');
})->name('eshop.edit');
```

my controller:

```
public function edit_eshop(Eshop $eshop,Request $request){
        if ($request->method() == 'POST'){            
            
            $eshop->title = $request->get('title');
            $eshop->link = $request->get('link');
            $eshop->telephone = $request->get('telephone');
            $eshop->email = $request->get('email');
            $eshop->payathome = $request->get('payathome');
            $eshop->paywithcard = $request->get('paywithcard');
            $eshop->tags = $request->get('tags');
            if($eshop->save()){
                echo "Το eshop δημιουργήθηκε επιτυχώς.";
                return redirect('/eshops');
            };
        };        
        return view('edit_eshop', ['eshop' => $eshop]);
    }
```

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Ονομασία eshop" class="form-control" value={{ $eshop->title }}>
     <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Ηλεκτρονική διεύθυνση eshop" class="form-control"  value={{ $eshop->link }}>
...
</form>
```

...

It suggests me :

> $eshop is undefined
> Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace `{{ $eshop }}` with `{{ $eshop ?? '' }}`

I 've already tried this , but keep getting empty fields in the form.

Comment: Because of your `if` statement of this line `if($eshop->save())` you return `return redirect('/eshops');`

Comment: even if i comment out the whole function the problem remains the same

Comment: If you comment out everything and just `dd($eshop);` then what is the output?

Comment: i get " Undefined variable $eshop (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/alleshops/resources/views/edit_eshop.blade.php) " . i forgot to mention that when i use it like that : Route::any('/edit_eshop/{eshop}', [EshopsController::class, 'edit_eshop'])->name('eshop.edit'); it works fine

Comment: your mentioned function on this post accept a post request. Can you access the page `edit_eshop.blade.php` on get request?

Comment: No i can not access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting this error, because your controller method never called from your route. Change your route :

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
  ->any('/edit_eshop/{eshop}', 'App\Http\Controllers\YourController@edit_eshop')
  ->name('eshop.edit');
```

Comment: Change `App\Http\Controllers\YourController` name with your controller name and change the path, if your path is different